# J2Bugzilla Fatal Error parsing server response - methodResponse

Tags: java, xml-rpc, bugzilla

I updated a product in my Bugzilla server, inserting some new components and deleting others.
After that, everytime I try to run a code that retrieves these components, I get the following error:

> An unknown error was encountered; fault code: 0 : Failed to parse
>   server's response: O tipo de elemento methodResponse" deve ser
>   encerrado pela tag final correspondente "<\methodResponse>".

(It's a localized message generated by j2bugzilla, but it basically means that the element  must be closed with a <\methodResponse> tag).

The code in which I'm getting the error is this:

```
GetLegalValues get = new GetLegalValues(GetLegalValues.Fields.COMPONENT);
bugzilla.executeMethod(get); // Here is where the error occurs
values = get.getLegalValues();
for(String value : values) {
    componentComboBox.addItem(value);
}
```

I have the same code retrieving versions, prioritues, platforms, OS... but the error is only thrown when looking for components. I'm using j2bugzilla 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: products and components are not allowed to have special characters in their names. Although Bugzilla accepts those characters in their names, `XmlRpcClient` from Apache is not able to understand them, and throws a `XmlRpcClientException`.